# Broken package list in kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -f
When I try this in terminal. [It says The package list or status file  could not be parsed or open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjGeU.png)
What should I do?. Please help me immediately. Thanks! :D

Answer (score 0):

Try using older file status,execute the following commands:
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/status /var/lib/dpkg/status.bad
sudo cp /var/lib/dpkg/status-old /var/lib/dpkg/status
sudo apt-get update

If the above solution doesn't work try removing all designated files using(one at a time):
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
sudo apt-get update

You might like to have a look at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PackageManagerTroubleshootingProcedure